# Why do these safety instructions have a ruler on them?

Tags: safety

I was on a Wizz Air flight the other day and the safety instructions leaflet had a CM ruler running down the side of it.

What is the purpose of this?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like just a courtesy tool on the safety card, but doesn't actually have a requirement or purpose. Previous versions of their safety card did not have this courtesy tool.

[image: Wizzair Safety Card]
<sup>(Image Source: aviationfreaks.freeforums.org)</sup>

Comment: I'm quite curious: Is there any other airlines that put such courtesy tools on their safety cards?

Answer (score 2):

The rulers are there for measurement of anything you wish to measure in flight (which mostly includes measuring the sizes of the baggage of the consumer if there is a doubt about the size). Such rulers come in handy as big bags which are above the foretold measurements are quite common, so the flight attendants leave it up to the consumer to measure their own bags and not cause any hassle to the airlines.

Comment: Wizzair, as well as many other low-cost carriers, actually measure the carry-on luggage before entry to the aircraft if they doubt it fits, mainly because they charge a horrifically high surcharge if you need to check in your luggage last-minute due to size. The ruler on board on the safety card would rather not be fetched to do that.

Comment: Usually, your luggage size is measured ONLY if cannot fit in the given places, and that is when the ruler would be used

Comment: Ryanair has a [cardboard luggage checker](https://shannonchance.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/blog-ryanair.jpg) that they simply put over the luggage in the gate area. To check the luggage inside the aircraft would cause unwarranted delay.

Comment: @VivianjeetSinghSudan If it doesn't fit, that seems conclusive to me. It's hard to see how a ruler would help there.

Comment: @DeltaLima, because some airlines have a rule which states that the passenger can still carry a cabin luggage bag if it does not fit but is smaller than a given dimension, after paying a nominal fee